# Jaxb Enums with subtype

Tags: java, enums, jaxb

I have Country Enum.

```
@XmlEnum
public enum Country {    
 ....,ES,FR,....;
}
```

Country is used in a Product:

```
public class Product {
    ...
    @XmlElement(name = "Country")
    private List<Country> origin;
    ...
}
```

The produced output is:

```
<Product>
    <Name>egestas</Name>
    <Description>montes</Description>
    <Country>ES</Country>
    <Country>FR</Country>
</Product>
```

The Problem is I need to produce this kind of output.

```
<Product>
    <Name>egestas</Name>
    <Description>montes</Description>
    <Country>
        <ID>ES</ID>
    </Country>
    <Country>
        <ID>FR</ID>
    </Country>
</Product>
```

How can I produce the later output with Enums without using an adapter?

Comment: Why not using an `@XmlAdapter`?  The implementation of it would be trivial.

Comment: You have two more classes to maintain (Adapter and MappableCountry)
I would like to avoid Boilerplate code, as I have 10 More Classes like this one.

Comment: Do you really need to have the `ID` element under the `COUNTRY` element?

Comment: I Agree it is useless here but the schema is expecting it to exist, and I can't change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

A

```
class Country {
    private CountryId ID; //...
}
```

with

```
enum CountryId { ..., ES, FR,... }
```

should produce the XML as requested.

**Later**

Of course, this requires more code to create the element with one additional layer.

```
Product p = ...;
Country es = new Country();
es.setID( CountryId.ES );
p.getCountry().add( es );
```

Comment: This would result in code like. product.setCountry(Country.ID.FR)
Well this is one of the workarounds but not what I would expect as a user.

Comment: From what would you like JAXB to guess what you want if your Java classes don't match the XML structure??? BTW, see my addition.

Comment: BTW, product.setCountry(Country.ES) would be wrong even with the simpler structure. It's always product.getRepeatingProperty().add( x ).